# Bluetooth Connectivity Issues in Post ICS Versions

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am able to connect to an external paired bluetooth hardware first time. After that if i repeat connect/disconect procedures sometimes getting exception.

```
Exception = read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

and after many trials able to connect again.Sometimes second trial itself is successful

The issue is observed with  Devices:Nexux7(version 4.3) and MotoG(Kitkat)

Code for connection:

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(devAddress);      
socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

and calling socket.connect() from asynctask

Code for closing socket:Subject

```
if (in != null) {
            Logger.loge(CLASS_NAME + "." + "resetConnection", "in != null");
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // Log.d(TAG,"exception in closing inputstream - " + e.getMessage());
        }
        in = null;
    }
if (out != null) {
    Logger.loge(CLASS_NAME + "." + "resetConnection", "out != null");

    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // Log.d(TAG,"exception in closing outputstream - " + e.getMessage());
    }

    out = null;
}
if (socket != null) {
    Logger.loge(CLASS_NAME + "." + "resetConnection", "socket != null");

    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.d(TAG,"exception in closing socket - " + e.getMessage());
    }
    socket = null;
}
```

I have followed the links

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/UxY5xME6V5s

[Android Bluetooth: java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348789/android-bluetooth-java-io-ioexception-service-discovery-failed)

[Disconnect a bluetooth socket in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031796/disconnSubjectect-a-bluetooth-socket-in-android)

[android bluetooth can't connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763779/android-bluetooth-cant-connect)

None of the solution provided help me to solve the issue.

Any help will be appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Actual problem is once both the device the is connected, the socket will be open. When either one of the socket is closed, other one is not closed.When you try to reconnect the other device ll not accept the new Socket.

The solution is when any one gets disconnect you need to re-initialize the connection service on both the side,ie you need to close the socket properly on both the side. and go back to the listen mode. then only the new socket connection will accept.[click Here code reference using AndroiddChat example.](http://www.androidsourcehelp.com/2014/04/android-auto-connect-bluethooth-device.html)

Comment: We are unable to re-initialize the connection on both ends programmatically , as one of them is an external hardware, not a phone.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar problem when I built an app involving bluetooth connectivity. After searching for a long time, I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657427/ioexception-read-failed-socket-might-closed-bluetooth-on-android-4-3).

Comment: Are you still getting the **socket might be closed** exception?